# Cos'è una "vagliona"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Parlano di polismen che trovènno una **vagliona** di nove anni.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "vagliona" in questa frase? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo su nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vagliona è una variante di [guagliona](http://www.grandidizionari.it/dizionario-italiano/parola/g/guaglione.aspx?query=guaglione), cioè fanciulla, ragazza in dialetto napoletano.

> guaglione
>    > [gua-glió-ne]
>    > s.m. (pl. m. -ni; f. -na, pl. -ne) 1 dial., merid. Ragazzo, fanciullo:
>   sei ancora un g.; una bella guagliona

Anche nel forum di Wordreference, per [vagliona](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/vagliona.1338152/) si può leggere:

> "In Molise il dialetto è simile al napoletano: ragazzi si dice
>   uaglion', ragazze si dice uagliole, ma alcuni pronunciano queste
>   parole con la v al posto della u, cioè vaglion' e vagliole. Invece
>   esiste, ma non è usata, la forma uagliona (o vagliona)".